# Pass data from xaml.cs to .cs

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to pass some data from .xaml.cs to .cs . These data are email and password that user writes in textblocks on xaml page. Like that

xaml

```
<TextBox x:Name="email" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="510" Height="72" Foreground="#FFF1BDBD"/>
<TextBox x:Name="password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="72" Width="510" Foreground="#FFF1BDBD">
```

xaml.cs

```
public string Email;
public string Password;

public authorize()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    button.Click += async delegate
    {
        Email = email.Text;
        Password = password.Text;
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to pass this Email and Password to some class.cs in which I want to write a method for authorize. 
I've tried to find any information about how to do this, but I can't.
So, please help me, if you can, or give me a link, where I can find something about this.
Thanx.

Comment: google "uwp binding"

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
public static class SomeClass
{
    public static string Email;
    public static string Password;
}
```

Then you can simply say:

```
SomeClass.Email = "whatever";
```